# How can I associate an object that will be inserted into the database with one that has not yet been inserted using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am attempting to implement auditing in my MVC 4 with EF application as per this post http://jmdority.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/using-entity-framework-4-1-dbcontext-change-tracking-for-audit-logging/.

I have a class that inherits from DbContext and overrides the SaveChanges method. In this new SaveChanges method I am inserting a record into an Audit table.

An entity that can be audited:

```
public class Fruit
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long FruitId{ get; set; }

    public string FruitName{ get; set; }
}
```

And the model of the FruitAudit table:

```
public class FruitAudit
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long FruitAuditId{ get; set; }

    public long FruitId{ get; set; }

    // Auditing properties like modifying user and timestamps.
}
```

And my overriden SaveChanges method:

```
public int SaveChanges()
{
    var entriesToAudit = this.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(p =>
        (p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Added || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Deleted || p.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified);

    foreach (var entity in entriesToAudit)
    {
        using (var context = new StoreContext())
        {
            Fruit fruit = entity.Entity as Fruit;
            FruitAudit audit = new FruitAudit()
            {
                FruitId = Fruit.FruitId;
                // Other auditing properties set here
            }
            context.FruitAudits.Add(audit);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

An error occurs when a Fruit is inserted because the FruitId is not yet set when trying to save the FruitAudit record. The FruitId is auto-generated from the database but the actual Fruit object isn't saved until AFTER the audit record is inserted. How can I associated this FruitAudit with the Fruit being inserted?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a virtual navigation property to `FruitAudit` so that you have something like:

```
public class FruitAudit
{
    public int FruitAuditId { get; set; }

    public int FruitId { get; set; }
    public virtual Fruit Fruit { get; set; }
}
```

And your `Fruit` looks like:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int FruitId { get; set; }

    public string FruitName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when you go to `SaveChanges()` you just say:

```
Fruit fruit = entity.Entity as Fruit;
FruitAudit audit = new FruitAudit()
{
  Fruit = fruit;
  // Other auditing properties set here
}

...

context.Fruits.Add(fruit);
context.FruitAudits.Add(audit);
```

Comment: This works if all my object changes have associated audits, but some of them do not. In that case, I need them to be added in base.SaveChanges(). But that call fails when I've already saved changes during audits. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a `BeforeSaveChanges` which you can override too. It's difficult to understand your scenario, but if you have multiple conditions like that, perhaps it'll be of some use.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a copy of all the entity changes and then calling base.SaveChanges(). That will insert all the Fruits. Then I go through the copy of entity changes and insert audit records for each.